Inject Class type in spring component constructor
For genericity reason I have some components that have the folowing body:
@Component
public class MyClass<C> extends SomeAbstractClass<A, C> {

    public MyClass(SomeClass1 someClass1, SomeClass2 someClass2) {
        super(superMethod(A.class, C.class));
    }
}

MyClass is just a generic skeleton of my classes, they may or may not have some object in the constructor (represented by SomeClass1 and SomeClass2). The abstract super class takes two classes, here A is explicited, it is not a generic, therefore A.class is valid. But C.class is not valid, since it's a generic class.
So I tried this:
@Component
public class MyClass<C> extends SomeAbstractClass<A, C> {

    public MyClass(SomeClass1 someClass1, SomeClass2 someClass2, Class<C> clazz) {
        super(superMethod(A.class, clazz));
    }
}

This code compiles but Spring cannot inject Class<C> clazz, how can I do it?
Edit:
I also tried something that does work but I don't like it so much. I create a class for each generic type as such:
@Component
public class MyClassWithoutGeneric extends SomeAbstractClass<A, B> {

    public MyClassWithoutGeneric(SomeClass1 someClass1, SomeClass2 someClass2) {
        super(superMethod(A.class, B.class));
    }
}

The thing I don't like with this solution is that it is not very versatile nor maintenable
Thanks

I found a solution which I like more:
I now have a wrapper class MyClassFactory which have the desired dependencies and is something like this:

@Component
public class MyClassFactory {

    private final SomeClass1 someClass1;
    private final SomeClass2 someClass2;

    public MyClassFactory(SomeClass1 someClass1, SomeClass2 someClass2) {
        this.someClass1 = someClass1;
        this.someClass2 = someClass2;
    }

    public <C> MyClass<C> create(Class<C> clazz) {
        return new MyClass<>(someClass1, someClass2, clazz);
    }
}

